# Does South foul up the Django test runner framework?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-south

I’ve got a Django project, to which I added the South app about halfway through to make database migrations easier.

I use the Django unit test framework in a couple of limited places in the project, meaning I don’t run the tests regularly. I recently wrote some new tests for a new part of the code, and attempted to run them. I got the following error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: auth_permission
```

The traceback mentioned some South files (e.g. `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/test.py`). Could South be fouling up the test runner?

Comment: @SkylarSaveland: okay. If you've got some more detailed information, that would be helpful.

Comment: My problem was that south was overriding the test runner. Putting django-nose after south in installed_apps fixed my problem. That our migration tool would try to take over our test runner is pretty annoying, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Possibly* — doubtless I’ve done something wrong somewhere, but South’s documentation mentions possible issues here:

- http://south.aeracode.org/docs/unittests.html

I added `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False` to my settings.py file, and my tests ran fine again.

However, my tests don’t currently involve the database, so I might have to revisit this.

Comment: Same issue, and adding `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False` worked for me. I'd be curious what was causing the issue though...

Comment: Same issue but that didn't solve my problem. Do you have any clue why is this still happening to me?

Comment: i forgot to tell that i have try [this](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose#using-with-south) too without success...

Comment: @marianobianchi: I have no idea I’m afraid, haven’t revisited it yet. I’d suggest asking a question about it, including the specific details of your situation.

Comment: A common cause is maintaining migration order. Often say migration #5 for `app1` needs to be run before migration #2 for for `app3`. There are tools to add dependencies in south / django 1.8, but most people ignore them, because the local environment doesn't add migrations from scratch.. only the latest unapplied ones. Therefore you'll rarely run into migration order issues as you're building new migrations. Only upon executing all migrations from step 0 as is done with the test DB will you start to realize these issues. The only solution is to add inter-app migration dependencies.